# How do I add a dollar sign ($) to my html display?

Tags: html, razor

I have this code that displays an amount of money previously entered. All I want to do is display a dollar sign ($) before it. That's pretty much it, how can I do this?

```
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.rate_psf_yr)<br />
</td>
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.mo_base_rent)<br />
</td>
```

Comment: I have no idea what this is but you can try @Html.DisplayFor(model => '$'+model.rate_psf_yr)<br />

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?

Comment: You can also just put the `$` before the `@` on both lines as anything before the `@` is still in the HTML context (as well as anything after the method call, like your break tag).

Comment: I have now tried @digitalniweb and Jesse's suggestions, but unfortunately neither of them worked. It just displays the number, no $ at all.

Comment: Sounds like this is an issue with whatever template language you are using, not the HTML itself.  You could clarify the question.

Comment: @smithkm its razor from .net land

Comment: @DanielA.White Stack overflow comment race condition.

Comment: Why not `<td>$`

Comment: @smithkm This will probably sound stupid but I don't know which template language I'm using. I've never used html before this, this code was written by my predecessor and now I have to add a dollar sign to the values here.

Comment: @epascarello That unfortunately didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was in the wrong section of the code, there was another html section where adding the $ manually got it to appear.